# How do I add two range values together, then multiply it by a select tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im making a simple form to calculate the price of carpets etc, I have 2 range input fields with adjustable sliders that go from 0 to 100, and a select tag with drop down options with different prices, the calculation I want to do is **(range1 + range2)*selectoption** and then the total is put into the textfield **total** this is all without clicking submit so it gives you a live calculation, without the need of submitting the page, any ideas on how to accomplish this ?

```
<html>
<head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form_style.css">
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                object.onchange=function output(){
                var value1 = document.getElementById("width").value;
                var value2 = document.getElementById("length").value;
                document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = parseInt(width) + parseInt(length);    
                }           
            </script>
        </head>
    <body>
        <div id="form11">
            <h1>Form</h1>
            <form method="post" action="#">
                <table id="table11">

                    <tr><td><p>Width (m):</p></td><td><input type="range" name="width" id="value1" value="0" min="0" max="100"  data-highlight="true" onchange="calc"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><p>Length (m):</p></td><td><input type="range" name="length" id="value2" value="0" min="0" max="100" data-highlight="true" onchange="calc"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><p>Carpet Type:</p></td><td><select name="carpettype">
                                                            <option value="6.99">Carpet1</option>
                                                            <option value="4.99">Carpet2</option>
                                                            <option value="8.99">Carpet3</option>
                                                            <option value="3.99">Carpet4</option>
                                                            <option value="5.99">Carpet5</option>
                                                        </select></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><p>Total:</p></td><td><input type="text" id="total" name="total"/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td></tr>


                </table>
            </form>
        </div>


    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seing as you're using jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        // On any change in form.
        $("form :input").change(function() {
            // Fetch selected options.
            var value1 = $('form #value1').val();
            var value2 = $('form #value2').val();
            var selectoption = $("form select option:selected").val();
            // Output to text field.
            $('form #total').val((value1 + value2) * selectoption);
        });

    });
</script>
```

See [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N6RB6/).

Comment: Am i missing something mine is like for like but nothing is happening http://50.87.10.130/includes/form.html

Comment: @M0n5terBunny You need the `$(document).ready(function(){ ... }` part to tell jQuery to load it after the body.

Comment: added it still nothing :( could the other javascripts be effecting it at all ?

Comment: @M0n5terBunny Sorry, my mistake, you have to add `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });` - notice the missing `);` before.